# Best way to create a complete readOnly list of object

Tags: c#, list, caching, readonly, readonly-collection

I'm using `C# 4.0`, `Asp.Net`. I have a problem regarding the proper construction of a `readonly` structure within a custom cache I created.

**Details (summary) :**
My CacheManager class (singleton) uses, as parameter, an instance of the existing `MemoryCache` class and wraps around a few helpful methods to deal with supplementary stuff such as object life cycle within my custom cache.

That Manager deals with a simple `CachableObject` that takes three variables :

- `object`
- `DateTime`
- `int` (duration)

In summary, my custom cache Manager stores `objects` for a limited amount of time in order to protect my database from frequent big queries.

Lately, I tried to :

- Got back an object from the cache (ie : stored under the key `-MyList`)
- Casted it back to a list of complexe objects
- Translated the content of some properties for each complexe objects
- Stored again the freshly translated list of objects within the cache, (under another key `-MyTranslatedList`)

**The problem :**
During my testing, it appeared to me that both lists stored in the cache (raw and translated one) were refering to the same underlying objects. Therefore, once translated, those objects were actually translated in both lists. 
Since each list only has references to the objects, that's a perfectly normal behavior and a silly mistake from me.

**The question :**
As you can easily guess now, I would like to protect myself and other users of my singleton for that kind of mistakes.

I would like to insert (or store or get) any kind of object (or list of complexe objects) so they cannot be altered by anybody getting them through the cache. I would like the data within my cache to be readonly (and **deeply** readonly) to avoid having that kind of problem. I want anybody to **have** to create a deep copy (or even better, to **get one**) before starting to use the data stored within the cache.

**What I tried so far :**
I tried to make the `object` readonly. It didn't work as expected.

Since I'm often storing list of complexe objects, I've found the AsReadOnly method that return a `IReadOnlyCollection`, but while this prevents me from altering the list (add, remove) it doesn't protect the objects that are within the list.

I hope my explanation is somewhat understandable :) Is there a neat way of dealing with that kind of situation ?

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent someone from changing an object if he has a reference to it. If you really don't want to change the objects, you can make them `ICloneable` or provide a read-only interface for them.

Comment: You can use [Immutable collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769092%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: @Sameer Thank you for your answer Sameer. So far, from what I understood, Immutable collections provides thread-safe access to a list that won't change. It doesn't garantee that the element within the list won't be changed... Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: @Spo1ler Thank you for your answer Spo1ler. Mmmm, the problem is that, since I'm putting random object within my cache, I cannot alter all my objects to make them ICloneable. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class where the properties are readonly:

```
class ReadonlyClass
{
    private string p1;
    private int p2;

    public ReadonlyClass(string property1, int property2)
    {
        p1 = property1;
        p2 = property2;
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return p1; }
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get { return p2; }
    }
}
```

If the properties are objects/other classes, you should implement a clone function that returns a copy of the object. The clone function for the above class would looke like this:

```
    public ReadonlyClass clone()
    {
        return new ReadonlyClass(p1, p2);
    }
```

Best regards
  Hans Milling...

Comment: Hi Hans, Thank you for your answer. The thing is, I can have any kind of objects in my cache. It also include objects that are constructed outside of my source code, such as Entity Framework objects returned from queries.